# How to change string datetime format to another format using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to change `date` `time` concatenation and changing string input format to another format. I tried below code. Here, I can able to change the date format but need to `concatenate` current time before passing input date string.

My Code Below

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    let result = formattedDateFromString(dateString: "28 Aug, 2019", withFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy")
    self.resultLabel.text = result           
}
    
func formattedDateFromString(dateString: String, withFormat format: String) -> String? {
    let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    if let date = inputFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
        let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        outputFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return outputFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Expected output like :

```
28-08-2019 5:00 PM
```

Comment: @backslash-f I updated my question, please check it.

Comment: The code cannot work. Please compare the `dateString` with the input format. The string must match the format. The date string contains spaces and a comma, the input format does not. The input format contains slashes, the date string does not.

Comment: @vadian vale mentioned code below working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func formattedDateFromString(dateString: String, withFormat format: String) -> String? {
  let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
  inputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM, yyyy"
  if let date = inputFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    print(date)
    let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outputFormatter.dateFormat = format
    return outputFormatter.string(from: date)
  } else {
    print("nope")
  }
  return nil
}

let result = formattedDateFromString(dateString: "28 Aug, 2019", withFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy - h:mm a")
print(result)
```

Outputs:
"28-08-2019 - 12:00 AM"

In general I found [this website](https://nsdateformatter.com/) to be really useful when trying to reason about dates in Swift/Objective-C

Comment: Wow fantastic answer. Thanks @vale

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
func convDate(dateToConvert: String) -> String? {
    //Input Format
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "dd LL, YYYY"
    //Convert input date string to date
    guard let date = df.date(from: dateToConvert) else { print("Incorrect date format"); return nil }
    //Output format
    let outDF = DateFormatter()
    outDF.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY"
    let hourDF = DateFormatter()
    hourDF.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    hourDF.amSymbol = "AM"
    hourDF.pmSymbol = "PM"
    //format to string dd-MM-YYYY H:mm a
    return outDF.string(from: date) + " " + hourDF.string(from: Date())
}
```

example

```
print(convDate(dateToConvert: "13 Aug, 2019"))
```

Comment: This crashes reliably. And regular year is lowercase `y`

Comment: Ok, after the edit it will always show "Incorrect date format" and return `nil`. The input date format is still wrong.